# How to use multiple columns inside an algorithm, showing a step, and its complexity side by side

Tags: multicol, algorithmic

I would like to write my algorithm to multiple columns, showing a step, and its complexity cost side by side.

Any idea on how to do it?

Here is an example (not my document)
[image: An example]

Comment: can you show what did you try? How long is your algorithm?

Comment: I am a newbie to tex, so I don't even know where to start. My algorithm is 20 lines.

Comment: The package [algorithm2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e?lang=en) let's you make nice pseudocode. Although the complexity would be harder to show. It could appear as comments, right side aligned.

Answer (score 1):

If the algorithm is similar to your example, the tabular environment might be sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{l r r}
        \textbf{Compute:}&matrix dimension&runtime complexity\\
        \hspace{0.5cm}$A^\dag = (A^T A)^{-1}A^T$, $B^\dag=(B^T B)^{-1}B^T$&$k\times n$, $k\times m$&$O((n+m)k^2)$\\
        \hspace{0.5cm}$\textbf{a}_{\boldsymbol{1}} = A^\dag \cdot G_1$, $\textbf{b}_{\boldsymbol{1}} = B^\dag\cdot G_2$&$k\times r$, $k\times r$&$O((n+m)kr)$\\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I need it to be embedded inside the algorithmic package, since I also have if / then,  repeat, and I'd like to have the algorithmic styling. I will check our if the tabular can be embedded inside the algorithmic package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (with `longtable` package that allow automatic pagepreak 
and `array` package to write math without need of `$ $` each time.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}r<{$} >{$}r<{$}}
\text{\textbf{Compute:}} & \text{matrix dimension} & \text{runtime complexity} \\ 
A=A+B+C+D & k\times n, n\times m & O((n+m)k^2)\\ 
A=A+B+C+D &  n\times m & O((n+m)k^2)\\ 
%% this is a comment
%%  column 1   &  column 2  &   column 3   \\
%%   end comment
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I need it to be embedded inside the algorithmic package, since I also have if / then, repeat, and I'd like to have the algorithmic styling. I will check our if the your solution can be embedded inside the algorithmic package.

Comment: Also, where do you say when an array start? How can it differentiate between math on / math off?

Comment: @user2476373 `>{$}l<{$}` from `array` package, this mean `$` at begin of column and `$` at end.